Pre-staging large data files for parallel job execution
Apologies in advance if this is a mundane or unclear question.
I want to scale up a workflow on on a cluster to run a program concurrently on several nodes. The program in question references a large, database during its execution, so to avoid hardware contention, I want to pre-stage the database onto each node's local SSD device.
I am unable to SSH directly into the compute nodes, but I can use mpiexec, which has been my current, dirty approach to copy over the files before running the program:
mpiexec -n $NNODES --ppn 1 \
    bash -c "mkdir -p $LOCAL_SSD && rsync -av $LARGE_DATABASE $LOCAL_SSD"

Is this really the best I can do with regards to pre-staging data? I believe these SSDs are cleared after each job, and cannot be accessed prior to a job's execution, so is copying the data during the job my best option? Wouldn't a bunch of these copy operations in parallel also cause insane I/O contention?

Note that most supercomputer have a parallel file system (eg. Lustre), You can move data from your NFS to the PFS using frontal nodes (no need for a reservation unless it is so big that it will takes >30 min). Copying data to local SSD might be faster at runtime, but regarding the cluster/supercomputer architecture, this might cause a lot of data replication (and also be cumbersome since you need to do it at each run while the PFS data are persistent between runs). Be aware that the PFS is generally cleaned periodically (users are warned about this before) so you should only store a copy on it

On some supercomputers, the SSDs are all stored separately from compute nodes (eg. storage nodes with a high-performance interconnect). In this case, it can cause an heavy contention of the storage nodes due to the massive level of replication. In this case, the PFS is much better. In some cases, the compute nodes have their own truly local SSD (especially on HPC clusters without any virtualization). In this case, copying data the way you do is fine (assuming the SSD are designed for that -- that is with SLC cells so they do not die quickly).

AFAIK some submission system have things dedicated for that. Using MPI is not so dirty IMHO. If the number of nodes is big, you can archive data once (eg. tar possibly with a fast compression), and then broadcast data on all node more efficiently with MPI significantly reducing the contention on the source node. This is more complicated though... You can do that in Python for example (or similar scripting language supporting MPI) using modules like mpi4py. This is especially important if the source FS is a NFS since AFAIK NFS contention slow down all users (which is pretty annoying).
